# Create a HTML list based on value of a data attribute of div tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tree

I have a PHP [function](http://gist.github.com/dbjpanda/5074ff1b19c70cf64e6631fda79fa6b0) that generates hierarchical view of some blog posts according to their category, child category, grand child category and so on. It generates a string containing div tags with its data attributes. I want to convert those divs to html `<ul><li>` based on their value of attribute `aria-level`.

**Actual output from php method**

```
<div role="heading" aria-level="1">Test 1</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="2">Test 1.1</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="3">Test 1.1.1</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="3">Test 1.1.2</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="1">Test 2</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="3">Test 2.1.1</div>
<div role="heading" aria-level="2">Test 2.2</div>
```

**Desired Output using php/js/jquery/ any framework**

- Test 1

  - Test 1.1

    - Test 1.1.1
    - Test 1.1.2
- Test 2

  - - Test 2.1.1
  - Test 2.2

**What I have achieved so far ?**

```js
function buildRec(nodes, elm, lv) {
    var node;
    // filter
    do {
        node = nodes.shift();
    } while(node && !(/^h[123456]$/i.test(node.tagName)));
    // process the next node
    if(node) {
        var ul, li, cnt;
        var curLv = parseInt(node.tagName.substring(1));
        if(curLv == lv) { // same level append an il
            cnt = 0;
        } else if(curLv < lv) { // walk up then append il
            cnt = 0;
            do {
                elm = elm.parentNode.parentNode;
                cnt--;
            } while(cnt > (curLv - lv));
        } else if(curLv > lv) { // create children then append il
            cnt = 0;
            do {
                li = elm.lastChild;
                if(li == null)
                    li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
                elm = li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
                cnt++;
            } while(cnt < (curLv - lv));
        }
        li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        // replace the next line with archor tags or whatever you want
        li.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
        // recursive call
        buildRec(nodes, elm, lv + cnt);
    }
}
// example usage
var all = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("*");
var nodes = []; 
for(var i = all.length; i--; nodes.unshift(all[i]));
var result = document.createElement("ul");
buildRec(nodes, result, 1);
document.getElementById("outp").appendChild(result);
```

```html
<div id="outp">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Test 1</h1>
    <h2>Test 1.1</h2>
    <h3>Test 1.1.1</h3>
    <h3>Test 1.1.2</h3>
    <h1>Test 2</h1>
    <h3>Test 2.1.1</h3>
    <h2>Test 2.2</h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**Problem to be resolved ?**

As you can see above it is using **Heading tags** to sort. But unfortunately my category hierarchy are not limited to only 6th level. It may grow. So I want a JS/Jquery/any framework to convert some tags to ul/li structure based on their attribute value. If any changes from Backend side is needed I can change those attributes/tags to any from PHP side. If it can be done from PHP side easily then some example code snippets is also welcome. Consider the above div tags as a single string input. :)

Comment: Please always add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not only a link to an external resource (like jsfiddle.com).

Comment: I would personally like to see more realistic input and expected output. The dangling `blah` only adds confusion.  Where, in its earliest, rawest form, does the input come from? Db? Txt file?  What is the exact structure / format of the unprocessed data?  What is your exact desired output from the sample input.  Are you happy for the solution to be 100% php? (This looks fun.)  I don't like the look of that dot dot 2.1.1 -- looks messy/bad.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have removed those dangling words. My current output from php method ( https://gist.github.com/dbjpanda/5074ff1b19c70cf64e6631fda79fa6b0 ) is a string. As I told earlier it contains a string of divs E.g `<h1 value="96" data-order="1">Personal</h1><h2 value="98" data-order="2">Travel</h2><h3>A journey to Bangalore</h3><h3>A Journey to Bhubaneswar</h3><h2 value="97" data-order="2">Foods</h2><h3>What is Rasgulla sweet</h3><h1 value="84" data-order="1">Database</h1><h2 value="85" data-order="2">Basics</h2><h3>What is Database ?` .

Comment: `<h1 value="96" data-order="1">Personal</h1><h2 value="98" data-order="2">Travel</h2><h3>A journey to Bangalore</h3><h3>A Journey to Bhubaneswar</h3><h2 value="97" data-order="2">Foods</h2><h3>What is Rasgulla sweet</h3><h1 value="84" data-order="1">Database</h1><h2 value="85" data-order="2">Basics</h2><h3>What is Database ?` is what it contains after you: 1. Replace the placeholders 2. Concatenate values 3. Use recursion.  Right?  I don't want to have to parse valid html if I can just use a query's raw result set.  It's not good practice for me to replace your replacement content.

Comment: Also, performing recursive queries on your database is a performance killer.  How many rows are in this table?  In many cases, it is better to make a single query, then use recursion on the complete result set.  Otherwise you are going to be keeping your database too busy.

Comment: @mickmackusa No worry for performance. We currently need to solve this question particularly.

Comment: Work is busy right now.  Perhaps some inspiration can be drawn from this post which makes replacements based on the count of a substring (aria level value in your case).  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/214837/141885  this is actually a process after your recursive process.  I would personally do this in one step, but I don't have time and I don't know if you are in a rush.

Comment: Thanks for your response again from your busy schedule. I tried to understand from that link. But I couldn't relate it with my problem. I am in a rush to complete it though. So when you have time could you please try it once. At least some pseudo code.